# How to reduce canvas size in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I reduce canvas size after increasing it?

For example, if my current canvas size is width: 1200px And height: 1400px, then I increased it to width: 1500px and height: 1800px. Now I want to reduce it a little bit, to width: 1400 and height: 1600px.

How do I do this?

Comment: Under Image —> Canvas Size?

Comment: Surely, if you figured out how to increase the size, you can figure out how to decrease it...

Comment: I think you can use a Crop tool.

Comment: I'm using the crop tool for this too. But the approach from @laurenimpsum shold work fine too

Answer (score 4):

Lauren clearly covered it but I'll post as an answer to accept

Choose `image > Canvas Size`

[image]

Then input your new canvas size and then select `ok`

[image]